# Why are bookmarks showing up in recently bookmarked when I did't bookmark them in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Bookmarks are showing up in recently bookmarked that I have NOT bookmarked! Am I hacked? Firefox is my browser where I have my bookmarks.

Comment: Do you have any sort of bookmark synchronization on? Maybe Firefox sync or xMarks?

Answer (score 2):

What sort of bookmarks? Have you visited the page before? Are the pages full of ads or scams?

My guess is you accidentally hit ctrl+D instead of ctrl+F, which bookmarks pages.

Comment: +1 Was typing the exact same thing but you beat me to it. :)